# Sending Multipart PDU SMS by AT Command

Tags: c#, sms, at-command, pdu

I have successfully sent a multipart pdu sms,

The problem is when i try to send this SMS to a number on a different network it gives me the following error :

```
+CMGS ERROR:500
```

Please can any one tell me what should i do.

```
        atCommandStr = "AT+CMGF=0\r";
        comPort.WriteLine(atCommandStr + (char)13);
        Console.WriteLine(comPort.ReadExisting());

        Thread.Sleep(2000);

        for (int i = 0; i < number_of_parts; i++)
        {
            int oct = (messagesParts[i].ToCharArray().Count() / 2) -1;

            atCommandStr = "AT+CMGS=" + oct + "\r";
            comPort.WriteLine(atCommandStr + (char)13);
            Console.WriteLine(comPort.ReadExisting());

            Thread.Sleep(2000);

            string path;
            path = messagesParts[i] + Char.ConvertFromUtf32(26);
            comPort.WriteLine(path + (char)13);

            for (int a = 0; a < 100; a++)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(2000);

                string t = comPort.ReadExisting();
                Console.WriteLine(t);

                if (t != "" && t.Contains("CMGS") || t.Contains("ERROR"))
                {

                    break;
                }
            }

            //Console.WriteLine(comPort.ReadExisting());
        }
```

Comment: Hi! Please help me to build correct PDU header. Would be great if you can share the test project to send multipart SMS in PDU mode. Thank you! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51053983/cannot-send-sms-more-then-140-via-huawei-usb-stick-modem

Answer (score 0):

Did the modem really return `+CMGS ERROR:500` and not `+CMS ERROR: 500`? Because in that case, your modem is not compliant with the [27.005](http://www.3gpp.org/ftp/Specs/html-info/27005.htm) standard which specifies `if sending fails: +CMS ERROR: <err>`.

Error code 500 means `unknown error`, so that does not help very much. But I would guess that your length calculation is wrong. From the standard:

```
<length> must indicate the number of octets coded in the TP layer data unit
to be given (i.e. SMSC address octets are excluded).
```

Is it correct to subtract 1 after dividing by 2? Try to decode exactly what will be sent on TP layer. Try to increase/decrease the length a bit and see if it makes any difference.

---

Also, since atCommandStr already contains `\r` you should not include the `+ (char)13` in

```
comPort.WriteLine(atCommandStr + (char)13);
```